# How to load initial data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Does anyone know how to populate mongodb with initial data? For example, with a traditional SQL database, you can put all your SQL statements in a textfile, then load that using a SQL command. This is extremely useful for unit testing.

Is it possible to do this with the mongo shell? For example, write down a list of shell statements into a file, and get the mongo shell to read the file and execute the statements.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`./mongo server:27017/dbname --quiet my_commands.js`

In my_commands.js:

```
db.users.insert({name:"john", email:"john@doe.com", age:12});
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [mongoimport](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongoimport) tool that comes with MongoDB to import **raw data**.

To **run scripts** from a file, e.g. to recreate indexes, pass the file name as a command line argument:

```
mongo file.js "another file.js"
```

Comment: I think you need to specify a DB